# DLL module can't be found after updating to latest Windows 10, version 2004

Tags: windows-10, software-update

I recently updated my Windows 10 Pro to version 2004.  Since then I've had clunky experiences, having to shutdown the computer to get out of trouble.  I am getting a notification saying:

> Unable to load DLL iaStorAfserviceApi.dll. The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT:0x8).

The computer is still functional, and I do not want to "reset" because that would require a complete reinstallation of my other software.  I tried restore point without any results. I don't have a recovery disc.

Comment: What program is giving that notification? Can you provide a screen shot?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the Intel Optane software was installed in error during the auto-update
installation of the Intel Storage Drivers.
This usually gives the error of:

[image]

Click on Start and run "Add or remove programs".
In the list, click on "Intel Optane Pinning Explorer Extensions"
and then click "Uninstall". Preferably reboot afterward.

Comment: The proper resolution to this problem is the author should repair the installation and remove the old pinning package by uninstalling it in the Device Manager, uninstalling it from Add or Remove Programs will not get rid of the error.

Comment: I removed Intel Optane Pinning Explorer Extensions as suggested by one person.  This itself turned out to be a clunky exercise, but eventually it got removed.  It's been several minutes now, and I haven't gotten the error message so far.  I will keep my fingers crossed.  But now that I see other comments, which explained that there was a repair option, I wonder what I should do if anything now that I no longer have the "file."

Answer (score 0):

> I recently updated my Windows 10 Pro to version 2004. Since then I've had clunky experiences, having to shut down the computer to get out of trouble

There are known issues with Intel Optane™ Memory Pinning with `Windows 10 version 2004`.  In order to resolve properly, you must repair the installation of `Intel Optane Pinning Explorer Extensions`, then uninstall Intel® Pinning Shell Extensions from within `Device Manager`.

> 1. Run `appwiz.cpl`
> 2. Locate and highlight **Intel Optane Pinning Explorer Extensions**.
> 3. Click **Repair**.

You must now remove the old pinning package in order to prevent error the next time Windows reboots.

> 1. Open **Device Manager**
> 2. Expand the Software components field.
>
> [image]
>
> 3. Right-click the **Intel® Pinning Shell Extensions** field and select **Uninstall Device**.
> 4. Check the box that states **Delete the driver software for this device**. and click **Uninstall**.
> 5. Reboot

Source: [How to Resolve Intel® Optane™ Memory Pinning Error: 'Unable to load DLL ‘iaStorAfsServiceApi.dll'' Encountered](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000056299/memory-and-storage.html)

Comment: I posted this already but not in direct response to you: I removed Intel Optane Pinning Explorer Extensions as suggested by one person. This itself turned out to be a clunky exercise, but eventually it got removed. It's been several minutes now, and I haven't gotten the error message so far. I will keep my fingers crossed. But now that I see other comments, which explained that there was a repair option, I wonder what I should do if anything now that I no longer have the "file."

Comment: @RonMcC - The reason I submitted my own answer is due the what I perceived to be an accuracy issue with the other answer.  The instructions I provided were provided by Intel back in March when the issue was first discovered.

Comment: Thanks.  I still don't know what are the consequences of not having the Optane file that I managed to remove.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Your supposed to reinstall and/or repair the installation and only remove the device manager device (per instructions)

Comment: Ramhound Thanks.  I managed to restore Optane.  So, I am back to square one. Will try instructions after I mentally recover from dealing with the mess I got into by removing Optane.